# Subclassing Swift Double / Operator Overloading typealias

Tags: swift, types, operator-overloading, subclassing

I'd like to be able to subclass Double with some custom types in my swift code so I can do some introspection and operator overloading later on.

This is semantically what I want to be able to write:

```
class Frequency: Double {}

class Period: Double {
    init(_ frequency: Frequency) {
        let period: Double = 1 / frequency
        self.init(period)
    }
}


let a = Double(1)
print(type(of: a))  // Double

let b = Frequency(2)
print(type(of: b))  // Frequency

let c = Period(a)
print(type(of: c))  // Period == 1

let d = Period(b)
print(type(of: d))  // Period == 0.5
```

Feel like what I'm trying to do should be posible as Swift is a strictly typed language.

I've looked at typealiases as well, but you can't operator overload with those. Also looked at the FloatingPoint protocol but doesn't seem to help me.

Comment: `Double` is a struct and it can't be extended.

Comment: @rmaddy unfortunately not. I was wondering if there's a different approach. Maybe protocols?

Answer (score 1):

while this is not possible, I created a class a while ago, which addressed a similar issue. I was in need of a polyvalent variable class, for ease of synthax in currency strings, and ended up with something like bellow. So far it's working great, and I've been using it as mortar for many advanced subclasses i've built since then. It does what you wish, which if you can see in the Frequency subclass, becomes a matter of tweaking the `init` override for each use case.
While the class is large, and the methods bulky, feel free to tweak and modify however you see fit, or if you find simpler approaches. I uploaded it to a gist file here so it can be read easily.

[Link to the class.](https://gist.github.com/murphman300/d7312e32b28e489c74ad79da8f85269d)

When used with your use case, it allows for the following, which seems to be what you want:

```
class Frequency : MultiVar {
    override init(_ value: Any?) {
        super.init(value)
        let current = double
        guard current != 0.0 else {
            print("Frequency Error: Something went wrong while subclassing \(self), established variable 'double' is equal to 0!")
            return
        }
        double = 1 / current
    }
}

let freq = Frequency(10)
print(freq.string) //prints 0.1
print(freq.double) //prints 0.1
```